# php - Abrir outra tela com o valor da tabela HTML

Tags: php, html

Estou precisando clicar no valor ID de uma tabela html e abrir outra página (novapag.php) fazendo echo desse valor que cliquei, sou novato e só conheço um pouco de php e HTML

[image: Imagem dos ID que preciso clicar e fazer echo em outra página]

```
<?php 
session_start();
 include_once("conectbusca.php"); 
 $pesquisaunid = $_SESSION['Unidade'];
 $pesquisa = $_SESSION['Senha']; 

 <?php 
 $sql = "SELECT ID, CPF,  Freada, Curva FROM tabela";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao retornar dados");
 $row = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

 while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
   $cpf = $registro['CPF'];
   $freada = $registro['Freada'];
   $curva = $registro['Curva'];
   $idautoinc = $registro['ID']; 

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$cpf."</td>";
   echo "<td align='center'>".$freada."</td>";
   echo "<td align='center'>".$curva."</td>";
   echo "<td><a href='novapag.php'</a>".$idautoinc."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 } mysqli_close($strcon); 
 echo "</table>";?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que você realmente deseja (valor da linha/tupla do ID ou o índice). Porém seguindo a lógica do código abaixo você consiguirá fazer o que pretende (acredito).

**Segue Código:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$idautoinc = 1;

echo "<form action='novapag.php' method='GET'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>
    <span>{$idautoinc}</span>
    <input style='opacity:0; width: 0px' type='text' name='id' value='{$idautoinc}'/>
</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Exibir'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

**Código da página declarada na** *action* **do formulário:**

```
<?php

$idQueFoiClicado = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
echo "Valor do ID: {$idQueFoiClicado}";
```

**Obs.:** Setei o valor na variável para representar o dado vindo do banco.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!